# How to know which smart contract have same wallet address as contract owner?

Tags: etherscan, bscscan

Is is possible to find out which smart contract transferred ownership to a same wallet address (different from the contract created owner) on Etherscan / Bscscan?

Let say i only have a targeted wallet address, and i want to know all smart contract currently have this wallet address as owner, how should i do? In particular for those smart contract which transferred ownership to this targeted wallet address after contract created. Does Etherscan / Bscscan have such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

No, Etherscan and BscScan do not have a built-in functionality that allows you to find all the smart contracts that currently have a specific wallet address as the owner. These block explorers primarily allow you to view transactions, contract code, and other details related to a specific address, but they do not provide a direct way to find all contracts owned by an address.

here is why? :
Smart contract ownership is not a standardized attribute : The concept of "ownership" in a smart contract is not a standard attribute in the Ethereum protocol (and by extension, Binance Smart Chain, which is compatible with Ethereum).

However, if you want to find out if a specific address owns a specific contract, you can do this by reading the contract's state on Etherscan or BscScan. If the contract follows the common pattern of having an owner state variable, this will be displayed in the "Read Contract" tab. You can then compare this address to the one you are interested in [blog.chain.link](https://blog.chain.link)